# Implementing nodeCount() and leafCount() in a binary search tree - java

Tags: java, recursion, nodes, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement `leafCount()` and `nodeCount()` to this recursive binary tree - program.
When testing it, these two methods (or the tests of them) throw `AssertionError`, so obviously they're not working as expected. I cannot figure out where I'm doing or thinking wrong. If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong or pinpoint the problem, I would be very grateful.

```
public class BSTrec {

BSTNode tree, parent, curr;

public BSTrec () {
    tree = null;    // the root of the tree
    parent = null;  // keeps track of the parent of the current node
    curr = null;    // help pointer to find a node or its place in the tree
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return tree == null;
}

private boolean findNodeRec(String searchKey, BSTNode subtree, BSTNode subparent) { 


    if (subtree == null) { // base case 1: node not found
        curr = null;
        parent = subparent; // the logical parent for the value
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        if (subtree.info.key.equals(searchKey)) { 
            curr = subtree;     // update current to point to the node
            parent = subparent; // update parent to point to its parent
            return true;
        }
        else { 
            if (searchKey.compareTo(subtree.info.key) < 0) { 
                return findNodeRec(searchKey, subtree.left, subtree);
            }
            else { 
                return findNodeRec(searchKey, subtree.right, subtree);  
            }
        }
    }
}


public NodeInfo retrieveNode(String searchKey) { 
    if (findNodeRec(searchKey, tree, null)) return curr.info;
    else return null;

}                                     

public void addRec(String keyIn, BSTNode subtree, BSTNode subparent, boolean goLeft) {

    if (tree == null) { // a first node will be the new root: base case 1
        tree = new BSTNode(new NodeInfo(keyIn));
        curr = tree;
        parent = null;
    } 
    else { // insertion in an existing tree
        if (subtree == null) { 
            if (goLeft) { 
                subparent.left = new BSTNode(new NodeInfo(keyIn));
                curr = subparent.left;
                parent = subparent; 
            }
            else { // the new node is to be a left child
                subparent.right = new BSTNode(new NodeInfo(keyIn));
                curr = subparent.right;
                parent = subparent;
            }
        }
        else { 
            if (keyIn.compareTo(subtree.info.key) < 0) {
                addRec(keyIn, subtree.left, subtree, true);
            }
            else { 
                addRec(keyIn, subtree.right, subtree, false);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void deleteNode(String searchKey) { 

    boolean found = findNodeRec(searchKey, tree, null);

    if (!found) // the key is not in the tree
        System.out.println("The key is not in the tree!");
    else { 
        if ((curr.left == null) && (curr.right == null))
            if (parent == null) 
                tree = null;
            else   
                if (curr == parent.left) // delete a left child
                    parent.left = null;
                else                     // delete a right child
                    parent.right = null;
        else // delete a node with children, one or two
            if ((curr.left != null) && (curr.right != null)) { // two children
                BSTNode surrogateParent = curr;
                BSTNode replacement = curr.left;
                while (replacement.right != null) {
                    surrogateParent = replacement;
                    replacement = replacement.right;
                }

                curr.info = replacement.info; // the information is copied over

                if (curr == surrogateParent) {
                    curr.left = replacement.left; // curr "adopts" the left
                    replacement = null;
                }
                else  { 
                    surrogateParent.right = replacement.left;
                    replacement = null;
                }
            } // End: if two children
            else { // delete a node with one child
                if (parent == null)  
                    if (curr.left != null) 
                        tree = curr.left;   
                    else                    
                        tree = curr.right;  
                else  
                    if (curr == parent.left)    
                        if (curr.right == null) 
                            parent.left = curr.left;        
                        else                    
                            parent.left = curr.right; 
                    else 
                        if (curr.right == null)
                            parent.right = curr.left; 
                        else                   
                            parent.right = curr.right; 
            } 
            curr = null; 
    }
} 

public void inOrder(BSTNode root) {
    if (root != null) { 
        inOrder(root.left); // process the left subtree
        System.out.println(root.info.key); // process the node itself
        inOrder(root.right); // process the right subtree
    }
}

public void preOrder(BSTNode root) {
    if (root != null) { // implicit base case: empty tree: do nothing
        System.out.println(root.info.key); // process the node itself
        preOrder(root.left);  // process the left subtree
        preOrder(root.right); // process the right subtree
    }
}

public void postOrder(BSTNode root) {
    if (root != null) { // implicit base case: empty tree: do nothing
        postOrder(root.left);  // process the left subtree
        postOrder(root.right); // process the right subtree
        System.out.println(root.info.key); // process the node itself
    }
}

public int nodeCount() {
    int count = 0;

    if (tree == null) {
        count = 0;
        //throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    else {
    if (tree.left != null) {
        count = 1;
        count += tree.left.nodeCount();
    }
    if (tree.right != null) {
        count = 1;
        count += tree.right.nodeCount();
    }
    }
    return count;
}

public int leafCount() {
    int count = 0;

    if (tree == null) {
        return 0;

    }
    if (tree != null && tree.left == null && tree.right==null) {
            return 1;
        }
    else {
        count += tree.left.leafCount();
        count += tree.right.leafCount();
    }

    return count; 
}

private class BSTNode {
    NodeInfo info;
    BSTNode left, right;

    BSTNode() {
        info = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public int leafCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int nodeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    BSTNode(NodeInfo dataIn) {
        info = dataIn;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }


    BSTNode(NodeInfo dataIn, BSTNode l, BSTNode r) {
        info = dataIn;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
   }
  }






  public class NodeInfo {

    String key; // add other fields as needed!

    NodeInfo() {
            key = null;
    }

    NodeInfo(String keyIn) {
            key = keyIn;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `nodeCount` logic has an error :

```
if (tree.left != null) {
    count = 1;
    count += tree.left.nodeCount();
}
if (tree.right != null) {
    count = 1; // here you initialize the count, losing the count of the left sub-tree
    count += tree.right.nodeCount();
}
```

Change to

```
if (tree.left != null || tree.right != null) {
    count = 1;
    if (tree.left != null) {
        count += tree.left.nodeCount();
    }
    if (tree.right != null) {
        count += tree.right.nodeCount();
    }
}
```

In your `leafCount` you are missing some null checks, since it's possible one of the children is null :

```
if (tree != null && tree.left == null && tree.right==null) {
    return 1;
} else {
    if (tree.left != null) // added check
        count += tree.left.leafCount();
    if (tree.right != null) // added check
        count += tree.right.leafCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
public int leafCount() {
    int count = 0;

    if (tree == null) {
        return 0;

    }
    if (tree != null && tree.left == null && tree.right==null) {
            return 1;
        }
    else {
        count += tree.left.leafCount();
        count += tree.right.leafCount();
    }

    return count; 
}
```

you're not allowing for the possibility that `tree.left` is non-null but `tree.right` is null. In that case, you'll try to execute

```
count += tree.right.leafCount();
```

which will throw a `NullPointerException`.

I think you should also rethink what you're doing with your instance fields `curr` and `parent`. These really should be local variables in whatever method you need to use them in. A tree doesn't have a "current" node in any meaningful sense.